# How to use Class.cast() for collection return of unknown type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm working on a data manager that can manage user-created Java data models.  It has a getter method to return all objects of a given class:

```
public <T> Collection<T> getAllForClass(Class<T> clazz);
```

I also have a filter object that stores the Class of the data to be filtered on.  It has a getter method as follows:

```
public Class<?> getFilterClass();
```

So when I apply a filter, I want to do this:

```
Collection<Object> objects = dataMgr.getAllForClass(filter.getFilterClass());
```

The compiler complains:

```
Incompatible types: Collection<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Collection<Object> where CAP#1 is a fresh type variable: CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?.
```

This doesn't work, either:

```
Collection<? extends Object> objects = dataMgr.getAllForClass(filter.getFilterClass());
```

I have a hunch that I need to use Class.cast(), but I don't know how.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Can't you just fix the `getFilterClass` to return a properly typed class?

Comment: There's no exception.  It won't compile (see compiler error I listed above).  And no, I can't change getFilterClass

Comment: does `Collection objects = dataMgr.getAllForClass(filter.getFilterClass());` works?

Comment: Are there generics on the data manager class itself and does the `dataMgr` variable have those generics correctly assigned?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the same behaviour but I get no errors: https://ideone.com/7wmgaT

Comment: No, I get the same compile error.

Comment: As @AntonioRagagnin said, the code compiles. If you have this problem, it may be at a different place? Try to copy Antonios Class into your IDE and compile it. Does it work?

Comment: @NickHolt The data manager stores collections of objects mapped by class:        Map<Class<?>,Collection<Object>> objectMap;  the getAllForClass method returns objectMap.get(clazz)

Comment: @MamaGeek if the code that I gave to you still produce an error on your machine, then, what Java/javac version are you using?

Comment: I got it to work finally by casting the retun as follows:  `Collection<?> objects = (Collection<?>)dataMgr.getAllForClass(filter.getFilterClass());`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it is possible that OP calls a `newInstance()` inside the `getAllForClass` method.

Comment: @MamaGeek OK, but never mind I was barking up the wrong tree, thinking it was to do with the mechanism where generics get disabled if they're not specified on the reference.  I've tried  @AntonioRagagnin's code and it works for me too - you should be able to write `Collection<?> col = dataMgr.getAllForClass(filter.getFilterClass());` with no errors